# Efficient way of saving array data at 3 decimals to text file

Tags: objective-c

I am saving accelerometer data which I store in arrays until my capture session is over.  When I touch a button, I save the data to a comma separated text file with 3 decimal precision and a I add a couple columns for showing if the data is within a range.
I have about 26,000 data points each for time, X, Y and Z values.  All my arrays are of long type and the float value I want is the array value divided by 1000.
My current method of formatting and saving the data takes an awful long time (~50 seconds), can someone please show me a more efficient way of doing this (maybe streaming somehow ?)?

```
dd= [dd stringByAppendingString:@"Secs,PitchG,ThrottleG,YawG,.,.\r\n"];
for (int lop=1;lop< numd+1;lop++) {
    if (labs(logX[lop])<1000 && labs(logY[lop])<1000 && labs(logZ[lop])<1000){
        grnT= @".1";
        grnB= @"-.1";
    }else{
        grnT= @"0";
        grnB= @"0";
    }
    dd= [dd stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f,%.3f,%.3f,%.3f,%@,%@\r\n",
                                                (float)(dtime[lop])/1000,(float)(logY[lop])/1000,
                                                (float)(logZ[lop])/1000, (float)(logX[lop])/1000, grnT, grnB]];
}
NSData* ifodata = [dd dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *sNTSpath= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.csv",docsDir,restartAtStr];
[filemgr createFileAtPath:sNTSpath contents:nil attributes:nil];
NSFileHandle *ntsfile= [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:sNTSpath];
[ntsfile writeData:ifodata];
[ntsfile closeFile];
```

Comment: My first guess is that using `NSMutableString` (`-appendFormat:...`) rather than creating a new immutable string for each data point would probably help to save some time. If not, I'd suggest to do some profiling (perhaps start with something as simple as logging few timestamps in the code to learn what part takes most of the time).

Comment: Btw: (1) From the data, you will be able to calculate the length of the string you're saving - make use of it when initing your `NSMutableString` (`-initWithCapacity:`). (2) If the string gets too long, you might find this approach too memory-hungry. Consider using `NSOutputStream` to write directly to a file instead.

Comment: Why does the data need to be in text format?

Comment: Thanks David, I will try that.  Droppy, I need an easy format that can be read by spreadsheet programs so that my user can graph to his hearts content.

Comment: david a. > Wouldn't I still have to create a string for each data line when putting it into a NSMutableString so that I know how many characters are in each data line so I can put it at the correct index in the NSMutableString or are you suggesting I pad each data line to a fixed length (I don't like padding :()?